# $mysqli->fetch_object cannot get a result to iterate through - PHP - Mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

I have the current code:

```
    Database::connect();
?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th> 
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php       
            $query = "SELECT * FROM app";  
            $dbr = Database::query( $query ); 
            while( $row = Database::$mysqli->fetch_object( $dbr->result ) ){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $row->title; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>        

<?php
    Database::close();
?>
```

and here is the Database and DatabaseQuery classes

```
class DatabaseQuery{
    public $result;
    public $mysql_num_rows;        
}

class Database{            
    public static $mysqli;   
    private static $db_name = '';
    private static $username = '';
    private static $password = '';   
    private static $host = 'localhost';
    private static $prefix = '';   

    public static function connect(){  
        self::$mysqli = new mysqli( self::$host, self::$username, self::$password, self::$db_name );

        if (self::$mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . self::$mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                . self::$mysqli->connect_error);
        }
    }

    public static function query( &$query ){
        $query = self::$mysqli->real_escape_string( $query );

        if ($stmt = self::$mysqli->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();            

            $DatabaseQuery = new DatabaseQuery();
                $DatabaseQuery->result = $stmt;       
                $DatabaseQuery->mysql_num_rows = $stmt->num_rows();                 
                $stmt->close();
                return $DatabaseQuery;                   
        }
    }

    public static function close(){
        self::$mysqli->close(); 
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error in my calling code: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_object()

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your following line:

```
while( $row = Database::$mysqli->fetch_object( $dbr->result ) ){
```

for this one:

```
while( $row = $dbr->fetch_object( $dbr->result ) ){
```

Because [**fetch_object()**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) is a method of mysqli_result object, and not of the general mysqli object.

Comment: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method DatabaseQuery::fetch_object() " Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your problem, but I would suggest looking into PDO's  a very simple way of accessing databases and working with them.

```
<?php       
        $query = "SELECT * FROM app";  
        $dbr = Database::query( $query ); 

            //Change this here since your method is query and not $mysqli
            while( $row = Database::$dbr->fetch_object( $dbr->result ) ){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row->title; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
```

If your dont mind I would say u are complicating your class a lot. If u have a reason then ok if not u could do it like this.

```
class Database{            
    private static $mysqli;   
    private static $db_name = '';
    private static $username = '';
    private static $password = '';   
    private static $host = 'localhost';
    private static $prefix = '';   

    public function __construct(){  
        self::$mysqli = new mysqli( self::$host, self::$username, self::$password, self::$db_name );

         if (self::$mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . self::$mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . self::$mysqli->connect_error);
        }
    }

    public function query( $query ){
         $query = self::$mysqli->real_escape_string( $query );

        if ($query = self::$mysqli->prepare($query)) {
            $query->execute();
            $query->store_result();            


            $stmt = $query->result;        
            //$query->mysql_num_rows = $stmt->num_rows();                 
            $query->close();
            return $stmt;                   
    }
}
}
```

The file that uses the class

```
 //Include the file unless u have a autoloader
    <tr>
    <?php       
    $query = "SELECT * FROM app";

    $dbr = new Database(); 


        //Change this here since your method is query and not $mysqli
        while( $row = $dbr->query($query)->fetch_object() ){


           echo '<td>'. $row['IDcolumnName'] . '</td>' ;
           echo '<td>'. $row['TitlecolumnName'] . '</td>' ;


    }
?>
</tr>
```

Comment: "Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Database::$dbr"

any ideas?

Comment: Use the class file I provided, i will include the caller soon.

Comment: where does your $stmt come from?

Comment: Yeah my bad, I think this could work now. Im more familiar with PDO's and I also have trouble with arrays :D

Comment: Just came back to this. I can't seem to get your class to work still :( Error is "Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in" on the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is broken:

```
    $query = self::$mysqli->real_escape_string( $query );
```

You do not escape the entire query. You escape data you're inserting into a query, e.g. if you had somethign like

```
 SELECT id, name, ... WHERE firstname = '$searchterm'
```

you'd escape the value in `$searchterm`. Escaping the entire query turns it into

```
 SELECT id, name, ... WHERE firstname = \'$searchterm\'
```

and you end up with syntax errors, because you no longer have quotes around $searchterm, you have a couple ignored characters as part of a bare string.

Then there's:

```
        $stmt->store_result();
```

`store_result()` returns a statement handle you can use to fetch results from later. You're not capturing that handle, so your DB result is simply thrown away, even if the query had executed properly.

Comment: I placed $stmt->store_result();  right into the DatabaseQuery class as the result property and now I am doing a mysqli_fetch_object and still no result.

Comment: Removing the whole escape string didn't make any difference to the current issue :( thanks for your help though!